# XAML binding Rectange.Fill SolidColorBrush to Color property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to display a TextBox and a Rectangle both show the Color property in another class. I use Caliburn.Micro and MVVM approach (I'm new at this).

My problem is that the TextBox writes the Color.ToString by default, but the Rectangle does not fill with the same Color, in fact the rectangle is invisible all the time. How to fill it?

Extract from XAML View:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,7,20,7"
         Text="{Binding Path=Design.EdgeHighlightOutOfRangeColor}"
         FontSize="12" FontFamily="Rockwell" Width="110" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="100,7,20,7">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Design.EdgeHighlightOutOfRangeColor}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Extract from C# ViewModel:

```
_designSettings = _settings.DesignSettings;
public DesignSettings Design
{
    get { return _designSettings; }
    set
    {
        _designSettings = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Design);
    }
}
```

Inside the DesignSettings class I have this property to be binded:

```
public Color EdgeHighlightOutOfRangeColor { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work unless you are using wrong namespace for Color property.

Color can be found under [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) and [System.Windows.Media.Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx). Make sure you are using System.Windows.Media in order to bind it with Rectangle.

With System.Drawing, it will come like below; without filled rectangle

[image]

Comment: Turns out you were right! I was unaware of two namespaces for Color, but I could not use the System.Windows.Media.Color struct directly and needed to add a converter, but still thank you for a guide

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to tell you this, but your code works fine for me without making any changes:

[image]

UPDATE >>>

If you resize your `Window` to make it larger, you should see the `Rectangle` appear from behind the `TextBlock`. This is one excellent reason *not* to use the drag and drop functionality of the Visual Studio designer and Toolbox. If you use rows and columns in your `Grid` correctly, you won't get this problem.

Comment: Sheridan is right, I've also tried it at it works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. The problem why you are not seeing your `Rectangle` is your are placing `TextBox` and `Rectangle` in the same `Grid.Row` and same `Grid.Column` of `Grid` hence `Textbox` is overlapping on your `Rectangle`. You will have to place them in different Columns.

Comment: I think with the Margin it should be visible?!

Comment: Sorry my friend,  but that's not correct. There is a `Margin` set on the `Rectangle` that positions it to the right of the `TextBlock` as can be seen in my screen shot.

Comment: I take that back... if the screen is resized, the `Rectangle` can be hidden.